# Großschreibung Englischer (Unter-)Überschrift für deutsche Texte

Tags: capitalization, english

Im Englischen gibt es eine Vielzahl von Großschreibweisen für Überschriften. Gelten die englischen Regeln auch, wenn man eine englische (Unter-)Überschrift für einen deutschen Text hat?

In meinem speziellen Fall ist der englische Teil durch einen Gedankenstrich abgetrennt nach einem deutschen Titel.

Es handelt sich um einen englischen Filmtitel (der international in englischer Titel-Schreibweise verbreitet sein dürfte und mit einem Großbuchstaben beginnt), im Deutschen schreibt man nach Gedankenstrichen allerdings (auch in Überschriften) generell klein weiter.

Beispiel:

> White House Down - ein politischer Kommentar

Answer (score 2):

Ja, denn das sind wörtliche Zitate aus einer anderen Sprache. Der ganze Satz, bzw. die ganze Phrase ist vollständig in einer Fremdsprache verfasst, daher gelten innerhalb dieses Satzes bzw. der Phrase die Regeln der Fremdsprache.

Davon zu unterscheiden ist der Gebrauch einzelner fremdsprachiger Worte innerhalb eines deutschen Satzes. Hier hat die Grammatik der Fremdsprache nichts mehr zu melden, das heißt Fall- und Einzahl/Mehrzahl-Unterscheidungen und auch die Großschreibung von Substantiven richten sich nach der deutschen Grammatik (Daher: *»Viele Graffiti, ein Graffiti«*, nicht *»ein graffito«*). Aber die Rechtschreibung des Fremdwortes wird unverändert aus der Fremdsprache übernommen.

Erst wenn ein Fremdwort schon sehr lange Teil des deutschen Wortschatzes ist, passt sich auch die Rechtschreibung an. Das ist dann der Punkt wo aus dem Fremdwort ein Lehnwort wird (französisch *bureau* → Fremdwort *Bureau* → Lehnwort *Büro*).

---

**Grammatik** ist jener Teil der Syntax, der sich damit beschäftigt, einzelne Wörter zu Phrasen und ganzen Sätzen zusammenzufügen. Daher hängt die Grammatik von der Sprache des Satzes ab.

**Orthographie (Rechtschreibung)** ist jener Teil der Syntax, der sich damit beschäftigt, einzelne Buchstaben zu Wörtern zusammenzufügen. Daher hängt die Orthographie von der Sprache des Wortes ab.